# How can i update two table in one query in posgresql

Tags: postgresql

Below is my code for updating two tables.

```
update  weighttracker , client  set weighttracker.wet_currentweight = 112,client.c_weight = 112  where client.c_id = weighttracker.wet_cid  and weighttracker.wet_cid = 88;
```

Comment: In postgresql documentation of update SQL command it states : "UPDATE — update rows of a table" : A table, so only 1.
Where did you find you can do more than one table upgrade at a time ? What is your need in fact ? Just lazzy writing 2 lines or you need to have 2 update done in the same *transaction* ?

Comment: Please don't just throw invalid SQL at us. Explain the underlying, **actual** problem you are trying to solve. This is usually best done by providing us with the table definitions, some sample data and the expected results (as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Comment: you have to write 2 update queries. If you want to handle such updates in a single go use, PostgreSQL Functions/Procedures(depend upon your version of SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following SQL:

```
with t as (
update  weighttracker
set wet_currentweight = 112
where wet_cid = 88
)
update  client  
set c_weight = 112  
where c_id = 88;
```